# Scale and axes of imported object relative to primitive (using Python API)

Tags: python, transforms, axis, units, collada

This is probably a no-brainer for people with some Blender experience but as a novice, I am confounded by how the axis and scale of an object imported from a Collada file can be made consistent with the primitives I have been using so far.

I have been trying to do an animation with some objects moving along curves defined by math equations and the folks on this forum have been very helpful in getting my animation to work as intended. I have been using objects created using primitives so far but now I want to switch to 3D models imported from Collada files (I am starting with a model of a simple LEGO piece). For some reason when I replace the primitive with the imported object, the scale and axes of the imported object seem very different.

I have scaled both objects to be of a similar size but my original code doesn't work very well. What is the best way to get the scale and axes of the imported object to be consistent with that of the primitives?

Here is a simple example showing both objects illustrating the difference in scale and axes. To get the same displacement I have to use 25 units with the imported object for 1 unit used on the primitive. I think it somehow makes sense since the size of the primitive cube (after scaling) is 0.2 meters or 20 cm while the LEGO piece is 0.8 cm (giving me a ratio of 25:1) but I am scaling the LEGO piece too and so I am confused. The axes (Y and Z) also seem switched.

I can also attach the Collada file I am using if I can figure out how ...

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')
bpy.ops.object.delete(use_global=True)

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cone_add(vertices=4)
cone = bpy.context.active_object
cone.scale = (0.1, 0.1, 0.04)
cone.name = 'Cone0'
cone.location  = (0, 0, 0)

bpy.ops.object.duplicate(linked=0)
cone = bpy.context.active_object
cone.name = 'Cone1'
cone.location  = (1, 0, 0)

bpy.ops.object.duplicate(linked=0)
cone = bpy.context.active_object
cone.name = 'Cone2'
cone.location  = (0, 1, 0)

bpy.ops.object.duplicate(linked=0)
cone = bpy.context.active_object
cone.name = 'Cone3'
cone.location  = (-1, 0, 0)

bpy.ops.object.duplicate(linked=0)
cone = bpy.context.active_object
cone.name = 'Cone4'
cone.location  = (0, -1, 0)

bpy.ops.wm.collada_import(filepath = "C:/Users/dshen/OneDrive/Desktop/blender/plate.dae", auto_connect = True, find_chains = True, fix_orientation = True)
plate = bpy.context.active_object
plate.scale = (0.2, 0.2, 0.2)
plate.name = 'Plate0'
plate.location  = (0, 0, 0)

bpy.ops.object.duplicate(linked=0)
plate = bpy.context.active_object
plate.name = 'Plate1'
plate.location  = (25, 0, 0)

bpy.ops.object.duplicate(linked=0)
plate = bpy.context.active_object
plate.name = 'Plate2'
plate.location  = (0, 25, 0)

bpy.ops.object.duplicate(linked=0)
plate = bpy.context.active_object
plate.name = 'Plate3'
plate.location  = (-25, 0, 0)

bpy.ops.object.duplicate(linked=0)
plate = bpy.context.active_object
plate.name = 'Plate4'
plate.location  = (0,-25, 0)
```